# URL-rewriting on Plesk using ISAPI_rewrite3 Lite

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, plesk

I am using Plesk Windows based web server with Windows 2008 server OS with IIS-6 for my e-commerce website.

I want to rewrite URLs for all dynamic pages, So I installed ISAPI_Rewrite 3 Lite on my web server also I had uploaded the `.htaccess` file with the basic rules as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ contactus.php? [NC,R]
```

I never worked before with ISAPI neither on URL- rewriting.

My doubt is

1. How should I proceed after installation
2. Should I upload `.htaccess` or
3. `httpd.conf` file OR This s/w has ISAPI_Rewrite Manager which gives place to edit `httpd.conf`, Should I write rules on this.

Anyways I had tried all these steps but unfortunately I couldn't find any remedies.
Any immediate solution will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ISAPI_Rewrite manager to load .htaccess or httpd.cong files. That's it. You PLESK may have permissions issues with ISAPI_Rewrite. All you need to do is to remove PLESK admin users from NTFS permissions for ISAPI_Rewrite folder and for .htaccess files that are located in the root of web-site.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is that you are using "Lite" version. One of [its limitations](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/Litever.htm) would be

> No support for distributed .htaccess configurations, directory and web site level configurations. Only one global httpd.conf configuration file will be loaded from Lite version installation folder.

So you need to use httpd.conf probably.